# Search text file for text above which pattern matches input

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, registry

I am trying to make my program display the text above the input text which matches a pattern I set.

For example, if user input 'FastModeIdleImmediateCount"=dword:00000000', I should get the closest HKEY above, which is [HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SCSI\Disk&Ven_ATA&Prod_TOSHIBA_MQ01ABD0\4&6a0976b&0&000000] for this case.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SCSI\Disk&Ven_ATA&Prod_TOSHIBA_MQ01ABD0\4&6a0976b&0&000000]
"StandardModeIdleImmediateCount"=dword:00000000
"FastModeIdleImmediateCount"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\SERVICES]

[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\SERVICES\TSDDD]

[HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\SERVICES\TSDDD\DEVICE0]
"Attach.ToDesktop"=dword:00000001
```

Could anyone please show me how I can code something like that? I tried playing around with regular expressions to match text with bracket, but I am not sure how to make it to only search for the text above my input.

Comment: Please provide more details... what is the text source? Do you perform a search on windows registry? Do you want to match keys or also values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your file is a .txt file, although it's most probably not. But the logic is the same.
It is not hard at all, a simple for() loop would do the trick.
Code with the needed description:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\test.txt");//replace your directory. We're getting all lines from a text file.

        string inputToSearchFor = "\"FastModeIdleImmediateCount\"=dword:00000000";  //that's the string to search for

        int indexOfMatchingLine = Array.FindIndex(lines, line => line == inputToSearchFor); //getting the index of the line, which equals the matchcode

        string nearestHotKey = String.Empty;
        for(int i = indexOfMatchingLine; i >=0; i--)    //looping for lines above the matched one to find the hotkey
        {               
            if(lines[i].IndexOf("[HKEY_") == 0)         //if we find a line which begins with "[HKEY_" (that means it's a hotkey, right?)
            {
                nearestHotKey = lines[i];               //we get the line into our hotkey string
                break;                                  //breaking the loop
            }
        }

        if(nearestHotKey != String.Empty)               //we have actually found a hotkey, so our string is not empty
        {
            //add code...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to split the text into lines, find the index of the line that contains your text (whether exact match or regex is used doesn't matter) and then backsearch for the first key. Reverse sorting the lines first might help.